# Symfony built-in server doesn't allow connection

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony for a while and today I upgraded my php version from 7.2.1 to 7.2.2 and added pthread support.

Since then when I start the Symfony builtin server (`./app/console server:start`) I get the usual:

> [OK] Web server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000

But then when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 it doesn't allow connection.

New PHP version is working fine.

Comment: What is strange is that when i use htop i can't find the process running. Same with lsof -i :8000, it gives me no output. But when i try ./app/console server:start again i get this error message anyway : ERROR] A process is already listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: From Symfony 3 i can spam the command server:start, i assume the process isn't created then. I have no error log and can't figure out what is happening for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried server:run instead and this errors instead :

`[Tue Nov 20 13:47:47 2018] PHP Fatal error:  The cli-server SAPI is not supported by pthreads in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Nov 20 13:47:47 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start pthreads module in Unknown on line 0`

After i googled it it seems that pthreads is restricted for CLI use only. It was indeed on the readme of pthreads github :

[Pthread SAPI Support](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads#sapi-support)